# unable to clear sessions in logout and not passing request to servlet it stops in between

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, session, servlets

I have a website suppose **adc.com** . which is using  `jsp` and `servlet`. It is having a login and when I login then it redirects me to **adc.com/userHome**. In userHome I have a logout button.

When I click logout button it is calling a servlet to logout and clear my sessions.

```
<input type= "button" value="logout" onclick="logout()"/>

<script>
function logout()
            {
                window.location = "/logoutServlet";

            }
</script>
```

When I click on logout it will call `logoutServlet` and it is got cleared the sessions and redirect to my **home page which is abc.com**.

In sometime when I click logout it is redirected to **abc.com/logoutServlet**.

Thus it is not clearing sessions. If we access userHome then it is getting.

My logoutServlet as follows:

```
public class logoutServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void service(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            HttpSession ss = rq.getSession(false);
            if (ss.getAttribute("uid") == null) {
                rs.sendRedirect("/");
            }

            rs.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            rs.addHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            rs.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            rs.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
            HttpSession session = rq.getSession(false);
            session.setAttribute("uid", null);
            session.invalidate();
            rs.sendRedirect("/");
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            //  rs.sendRedirect("/");
            RequestDispatcher dd = rq.getRequestDispatcher("/");
            dd.forward(rq, rs);
        }

    }
}
```

In most cases when I click it is logout and redirected to **abc.com**.

My doubt is that why in some times when click logout it is redirected to **abc.com/logoutServlet** and there it stops and with out forwarding it into servelt. So it is not clearing sessions.

Please help me to sort out.

Comment: Did you put a debugger on your LogoutServlet & line session.invalidate() & checked what is happening?

Comment: @underdog it is just stops on abc.com/logoutServlet  and it shows the home page. it means it is not even entering that servlet right??

Comment: Put a debugger on the servlet if the flow is entering the servlet it will stop at the place where you put the debugger so you will get to know what is happening.

Comment: ok i will put printwriter to track it!!

Comment: Buddy the problem is that in some situations it is not going to servlet but when i click login it is redirected to home page with abc.com/logoutServlet in address bar. I do not why it is not even going to servlet. it is the issue!!

Comment: @underdog it is not even passed to servlet in some situations and it stops on abc.com/logoutServlet. But shows homepage. Fully confused :(